# Are there any good reasons for applying Bayesian Networks these days?

Tags: bayesian-network

What reasons exist to favor bayesian networks over other, presumably more powerful, predicitve models like random forests or deep neural networks?

Comment: i am less familiar with DNN's - but i would presume that one of the reasons to continue to use Bayesian networks is that they are probabilistic models, that more intuitively (at least than random forests) give a probabilistic interpretation of outcomes and results